# Android, how to open UPI Payment Apps using Intent chooser, not working on Android 11 and 12 versions

Tags: java, android, payment, upi

I have developed an app for the payment system, i have to show all the available apps of payments installed on android system, I have implemented it but having some issues in some higher versions of android.
The intent chooser option is getting inflated in android 10 but not in above version.
Thanks

I have written the code successfully but having some issues in 11 and 12 versions of android.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the Your **startActivityForResult** code and **onActivityResult** code if this is proper or try to add the below line in manifest.

```
<queries>
<package android:name="com.facebook.katana" />
<package android:name="com.facebook.orca" />
<package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
<package android:name="net.one97.paytm" />
<package android:name="com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user" />
<package android:name="com.phonepe.app" />
<package android:name="in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping" />
<package android:name="in.org.npci.upiapp" />
</queries>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any common way to find payment apps?
Because many new apps introducing UPI payments so in order to resolve the new apps we may need to add in manifest and re publish our app.